# Combining plots with missing x-values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

This might be a duplicate but I couldn't find the solution, so here it goes:

I'm trying to combine the following dataframes into one plot. 
Df1:

```
quarter   count
2017-1    1
2017-2    1
2017-3    1
2017-4    2
2018-2    5
2018-3    2
```

with Df2:

```
quarter   count
2017-1    9
2017-2    16
2017-3    6
2017-4    15
2018-1    14
2018-2    17
2018-3    20
2018-4    16
```

However, if I run the following:

```
ax = plt.gca()
Df1.plot(x = 'quarter', y = 'count', ax = ax)
Df2.plot(x = 'quarter', y = 'count', ax = ax)
plt.xticks(Df2.index, Df2['quarter'].values)
```

things go wrong, as it just plots the '2018-2' and '2018-3' values of Df1 at the '2018-1' and '2018-2' spots. This happens I guess since there is no '2018-1' value at Df1. Any idea how to solve this? (And let the plot just be zero at 2018-1 for Df1?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1 = df1.set_index('quarter').reindex_like(df2.set_index('quarter')).reset_index().fillna(0)

ax = plt.gca()
df1.plot(x = 'quarter', y = 'count', ax = ax)
df2.plot(x = 'quarter', y = 'count', ax = ax)
plt.xticks(df2.index, df2['quarter'].values)
plt.show()
```

The output plot look like:

[image]